# Open User Profile In Chrome using PowerShell and Selenium

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I have found little to no info on this topic, basically I'm just trying to use selenium to open up a chrome profile so that the settings are saved to be used in each run of the script. Please help as I am new to coding and have never used PowerShell.

So far the only semi successful attempt with no errors is as follows but still does not work..

```
$WebDriverPath = Resolve-Path "C:\selenium\WebDriver.dll"
Unblock-File $WebDriverPath
Add-Type -Path $WebDriverPath

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$CD = $ChromeDriver.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\jshaw\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2")
$CD = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver

$CD.Navigate().GoToURL('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Just a guess: Try `New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver $ChromeDriver`, i.e. pass the options as an argument to the ChromeDriver constructor.

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out how to do this! This loads your default profile; however, there is an issue when you do this. If you have Chrome open already it throws an error. when Chrome is closed all good! Now I know why people use customized profiles.

````
$ChromeOptions.AddArgument(
"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\TweakAir\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
)

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($YourURL)```
````